# How do I get the totals for each month and YTD (SQL query)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to take to get the total of all the months pmts each month for each company then get the full "total" for the months into years to date "YTD" This is the table I have of the records. And the codec right under it.

2014 Total Production

```
    Jan-14  Feb-14  Mar-14  Apr-14  2014 YTD
Alpha corp  10  24  18  10  62
zeen corp   10  14  16  21  61
open corp   20  6   18  12  56
geez corp   15  5   14  8   42
mine corp   5   7   16  12  40
little corp 10  5   7   10  32
Vize corp   4   5   20  2   31
deng corp   5   9   8   9   31
nine corp   7   5   8   10  30
wash corp   5   8   7   10  30
hass corp   6   9   8   7   30
2014 YTD    77  97  144 222 445
```

and

```
Declare @year int
Set @year = 2014

select 
   a.first_name, a.last_name,
   Count(case when Month(b.funded_date) = 1 Then 1 else Null End) Janurary, 
   Count(case when Month(b.funded_date) = 2 Then 1 else Null End) Feburary ,
   Count(case when Month(b.funded_date) = 3 Then 1 else Null End) March,
   Count(case when Month(b.funded_date) = 4 Then 1 else Null End) April
from 
   tContact a 
Inner join 
   tContract b On a.contact_id = b.contract_id
Group by 
   first_name, last_name
```

Comment: That's a display problem, e.g. something you need to do in client-side code. Your query is returning the per-month data properly. It's not SQL's job to give you a total after all that. Youl **COULD** try mysql's "with rollup" option, but you'd be better off just summing in the client.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using MYSQL (Sql server 2008 r2)

Comment: MySQL is not SQLServer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server (based on the syntax), you can do what you want as:

```
select a.first_name + a.last_name,
       sum(case when Month(b.funded_date) = 1 Then 1 else 0 End) Janurary, 
       sum(case when Month(b.funded_date) = 2 Then 1 else 0 End) Feburary ,
       sum(case when Month(b.funded_date) = 3 Then 1 else 0 End) March,
       sum(case when Month(b.funded_date) = 4 Then 1 else 0 End) April,
       sum(case when Month(b.funded_date) <= 4 then 1 else 0 end) as YTD
from tContact a Inner join
     tContract b
     On a.contact_id = b.contract_id
Group by first_name + last_name with rollup;
```

If you have more than one `group by` column and you want just one summary, then look into `GROUPING SETS`.